# I have two pop up dialog box. I have the javascript. Currently only one of the pop up opens when both the links are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two pop up dialog boxes for the links in the footer Return Policy and Privacy Policy . I have the javascript and all the files.

Currently only one of the pop up opens when both the links are clicked. I want each link to open its own respective pop up dialog box.

The webpage where this is located is at http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/index.html

The javascript file is located at http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/js/popups.js.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the click tag on the surrounding span #dialog. So basicly no matter where you press in the span the same popup will open.

Then you display both Dialogs on top off eachother, with return policy being the last dialog, it overlays the other.

What you need to do is bind it to the links

```
$("#dialog a").click(function(){
    //centering with css
    centerPopup();
    //get id of the clicked
    var clickedLink = $(this).attr('id');
    //load popup
    loadPopup(clickedLink);
});
```

And then only show the click dialog:

```
function loadPopup(clickedLink){
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if(popupStatus==0){
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#"+clickedLink).fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}
```

---

**Updated version**

You could get the dialog ID by using the href and then do it like:

```
<a href="#privacyPolicy-popup" id="returnPolicy">Return Policy</a>
```

And

```
$("#dialog a").click(function(){
    //centering with css
    centerPopup();
    //get id of the clicked
    var clickedLink = $(this).attr('href');
    //load popup
    loadPopup(clickedLink);
});
```

And

```
function loadPopup(clickedLink){
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if(popupStatus==0){
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $(clickedLink).fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The first part works to work only on the a tags when clicked. The second part doesnt work and all I get is a blank screen. Both of my span#dialog have different id's so one method can be to say if a#returnPolicy clicked show #returnPolicy-popup, and if a#privacyPolicy clicked show #privacyPolicy-popup .

Comment: Try `$("#"+clickedLink+"-popup").fadeIn("slow");`

Comment: @PirateKitten didnt even think of that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how you have bound the event:

```
//LOADING POPUP
//Click the button event!
$("#dialog").click(function(){
    //centering with css
    centerPopup();
    //load popup
    loadPopup();
});
```

You have assigned this click event to the whole of the `dialog` span, so this will be executed whenever they click anywhere in that (even in the spaces between the links). It doesn't discern between the links.

Furthermore, in your loadPopup(), you have:

```
$("#privacyPolicy-popup").fadeIn("slow");
$("#returnPolicy-popup").fadeIn("slow");
```

So what is occurring is that both popups will be shown anytime anywhere in the `dialog` span is clicked.

As a hint, what you want to be doing here is somehow discerning between which of the links has been clicked (by, say, binding the click to each link rather than the dialog) and then only showing one of the popups at a time, depending on which link was clicked.

Comment: True !  Fixed the first part. Actually what I want is that... Both of my span#dialog have different id's so it can be to say if a#returnPolicy clicked show #returnPolicy-popup, and if a#privacyPolicy clicked show #privacyPolicy-popup. I just cant get the javascript to make this happen.